# Train GPT-2 on local machine, load dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, gpt-2

I am trying to run gpt-2 on my local machine, since google restricted my resources, because I was training too long in colab.

However, I cannot see how I can load the dataset. In the original colab notebook https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VLG8e7YSEwypxU-noRNhsv5dW4NfTGce there is the command 
gpt2.copy_file_from_gdrive() which I cannot use on my local machine.

On the github repo https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple they simply give the name of the file 
shakespeare.txt to the function gpt2.finetune and it works somehow, but this doesn't work for me.

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the [example](https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple#usage) correctly on GitHub, it loads `shakespeare.txt` if it is present on the machine and downloads it if it isn't. For a local dataset, I simply drop a txt file in the same folder and call it in `file_name =`.

You should be able to remove the logic around `if not os.path.isfile(file_name):`—it shouldn't be needed if you use a local file.